# Base class pointer: where to use new and delete

Tags: c++, c++03

I wonder where I should use the `new` and `delete` in the following class structure:

```
#include <iostream>

class StateBase {
public:
    StateBase( int val ) : m_stateInfo(val) {}
    virtual ~StateBase() {}
    virtual int getState() = 0;
protected:
    int m_stateInfo;
};

class StateImpl1 : public StateBase {
public:
    StateImpl1() : StateBase( 1 ) {}
    ~StateImpl1() {}
    int getState() {
        //std::cout << "stateimpl:" << m_stateInfo << std::endl;
        return m_stateInfo;
    }
};

class DeviceBase {
public:
    DeviceBase( StateBase* pState ) : mp_state( pState ) {}
    ~DeviceBase() {} // TODO or delete here? but then it's a bit asymmetric...
    virtual void work() = 0;
protected:
    StateBase* mp_state;
};

class DeviceImpl1 : public DeviceBase {
public:
    DeviceImpl1() : DeviceBase( new StateImpl1() ) {}
    // TODO d'tor here? but then base is left without valid ptr to "mp_state"
    ~DeviceImpl1() { delete mp_state; }
    void work() {
        std::cout << "DeviceImpl1 work: state = " << mp_state->getState() << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    DeviceImpl1 impl1;
    impl1.work();
    return 0;
}
```

Having the `delete` in the base class is asymmetric and less readable, I guess.
Using `delete` in the derived class (where the `new` is invoked) leaves the base class with a invalid pointer (if only shortly, but it's not clean).

- using it in derived class, setting ptr to `NULL` and and checking pointer for `NULL` in the base class could be an option
- maybe the whole design is flawed? if so: what's an alternative?

Update:
I can not use modern C++ because it will have to be compiled with a cross compiler < C++11.

Comment: "where I should use the new and delete" - In modern C++, practically *never* / *nowhere* since you should be using containers and / or smart pointers, *not* manual memory management. Also; stop using `NULL`, use `nullptr`.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile at all. What is `StateBase`?

Comment: I can not use modern C++ because it will have to be compiled with a cross compiler < C++11 (I've now added this info to question above). The code compiles as is with g++ 7.4.0.

Comment: Your code looks more or less OK to me. The ctor `DeviceImpl1()` performs a `new` and the dtor `~DeviceImpl1()` deletes what has been allocated in the ctor. On the the rhand I'm not sure why `mp_state`  needs to be allocated dynamically? Also it's hard to tell if the design is flawed because we don't know what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: In the end it's a question of ownership. Does `DeviceBase` _own_ the `StateBase` or does it just _contain_ it? I would argue that `DeviceImpl1` owns the `StateBase` (and `DeviceBase ` just contains it) since it's creating it and thus should be responsible for deleting it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: in short: a device shall be handled by a client. The client shall be agnostic of internals. Different device types have different means of communications and different states (all with common interface, communication left out in the minimal example above). The DeviceBase shall present a interface to the client which abstracts all those internals.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: I'd be happy not to allocate the stateImpl dynamically, but having it as a member in DeviceImpl1 and passing it's address to base doesn't work. The member is not yet initialized and the DeviceBase would use a bad pointer in the c'tor.

Answer (score 0):

Use `unique_ptr` to manage ownership/lifetime/memory:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

class StateBase {
public:
    StateBase( int val ) : m_stateInfo(val) {}
    virtual ~StateBase() {}
    virtual int getState() = 0;
protected:
    int m_stateInfo;
};

class StateImpl1 : public StateBase {
public:
    StateImpl1() : StateBase( 1 ) {}
    ~StateImpl1() {}
    int getState() {
        return m_stateInfo;
    }
};

class DeviceBase {
public:
    DeviceBase( std::unique_ptr<StateBase> ) : mp_state( std::move(pState) ) {}
    virtual ~DeviceBase() {}
    virtual void work() = 0;
protected:
    std::unique_ptr<StateBase> mp_state;
};

class DeviceImpl1 : DeviceBase {
public:
    DeviceImpl1() : DeviceBase( std::make_unique<StateImpl1>() ) {}
    ~DeviceImpl1() = default;
    void work() {
        std::cout << "DeviceImpl1 work: state = " << mp_state->getState() << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    DeviceImpl1 impl1;
    impl1.work();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see you can't use modern C++. I'd still try to create a `unique_ptr` like library type to manage this, even in C++03.

Answer (score 0):

In modern C++, you would 1. figure out the desired ownership semantics and then 2. express them using appropriate memory management tools, such as smart pointers. Notably, you never manually do memory management. That's effort that should be encapsulated in a class whose sole responsibility is memory management (see [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class StateBase {
public:
    StateBase( int val ) : m_stateInfo(val) {}
    virtual ~StateBase() {}
    virtual int getState() = 0;
protected:
    int m_stateInfo;
};

class StateImpl1 : public StateBase {
public:
    StateImpl1() : StateBase( 1 ) {}
    ~StateImpl1() {}
    int getState() {
        //std::cout << "stateimpl:" << m_stateInfo << std::endl;
        return m_stateInfo;
    }
};

class DeviceBase {
public:
    // Constructor says: Give me exclusive ownership of a StateBase.
    DeviceBase(std::unique_ptr<StateBase> pState) : mp_state(std::move(pState)) {}

    // Destructor (implicitly generated) takes care of cleanup.

    virtual void work() = 0;
protected:
    std::unique_ptr<StateBase> mp_state;
};

class DeviceImpl1 : DeviceBase {
public:
    DeviceImpl1() : DeviceBase(std::make_unique<StateImpl1>()) {}

    // Base class constructor handles cleanup.

    void work() {
        std::cout << "DeviceImpl1 work: state = " << mp_state->getState() << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    DeviceImpl1 impl1;
    impl1.work();
    return 0;
}
```

All we did here was to clarify that `DeviceBase` holds unique ownership of a `StateBase`. By doing that, we can eliminate all the destructors (`std::unique_ptr` handles the memory management for us, see also [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization)). I would prefer `= default;` over an empty destructor implementation but that's largely immaterial. The automatically generated destructor of `DeviceBase` will call the `unique_ptr` destructor which will `delete` the stored `StateBase` instance.

Note that your original code does not follow the [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), therefore you would run into problems (read: double free etc.) when attempting to copy instances of your class. In the above code using `std::unique_ptr`, the `DeviceBase` and `DeviceImpl1` classes cannot be copied (because the `std::unique_ptr` member cannot be copied).

Comment: Unfortunately `unique_ptr` is only available with `C++11`. Afaik `auto_ptr` is the only smart pointer available in C++03, and it's considered harmful.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit public base class :

```
#include <iostream>

class StateBase {
public:
    StateBase(int val) : m_stateInfo(val) {}
    virtual ~StateBase() {}
    virtual int getState() = 0;
protected:
    int m_stateInfo;
};

class StateImpl1 : public StateBase {
public:
    StateImpl1() : StateBase(1) {}
    ~StateImpl1() {}
    int getState() {
        //std::cout << "stateimpl:" << m_stateInfo << std::endl;
        return m_stateInfo;
    }
};

class DeviceBase {
public:
    DeviceBase(StateBase* pState) : mp_state(pState) {}
    ~DeviceBase() {} // TODO or delete here? but then it's a bit asymmetric...
    virtual void work() = 0;
protected:
    StateBase* mp_state;
};

class DeviceImpl1 : **public DeviceBase** { // Change is here
public:
    DeviceImpl1() : DeviceBase(new StateImpl1()) {}
    // TODO d'tor here? but then base is left without valid ptr to "mp_state"
    ~DeviceImpl1() { delete mp_state; }
    void work() {
        std::cout << "DeviceImpl1 work: state = " << mp_state->getState() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

How you can initialize the DeviceImpl1 instance impl1 & call delete to execute both of the destructors :

```
int main() {
    DeviceImpl1* impl1 = new DeviceImpl1();
    DeviceBase* base = impl1;
    impl1->work();
    delete base; // This will execute both of the destructor.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've added the "public" in my question - had just forgotten. As I mentioned in my question, this solution looks more "symmetric" (`new` in ctor, `delete` in dtor) but leaves the BaseDevice d'tor with an invalid `mp_state` because the d'tor of the derived class is executed before the d'tor of base class.